# Passing variables to Camunda subprocess

Tags: business-process-management, camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm trying to model a document workflow using Camunda 7.12. One of the requirements is that the user can define a due date for the whole process, and the system must send a remainder a couple of days before that deadline.

I was suggested to define a subprocess with a timer event that triggers when the date selected by the user in the start form is reached.

So, I defined the following subprocess in the model:

[image: Subprocess]

The timer event has the following properties:

[image: Timer event properties]

The `due_date` variable is entered by the user in a form when the he starts the process, but I don't know how I can pass it (or if it's even possible) to the remainder subprocess.

Any ideas? Or alternatives on how it could be done?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

A related issue was fixed in 
https://jira.camunda.com/browse/CAM-9303

and the related unit test 
(https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/33601f3026341882afae321611dfe4e8dfd31d2c/engine/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/test/bpmn/event/timer/StartTimerEventTest.java#L1351-L1446)

passes on camunda 7.12 and also on the @SpringBootTest I created.

However, I saw the same issue when testing manually via **tasklist** using this process:
https://cawemo.com/share/6bf324bb-4002-490c-8739-7ca94803acc0

Tasklist uses an API which differs from the call used in the tests.

Possible workarounds I see:

a) Wrap API used in test *runtimeService().createProcessInstanceByKey(...)* with own REST service and start via this endpoint.

b) Change process model and move process into embedded sub process, then attach intermediated timer event to it. This creates the variable before the event is registered. Example here:

https://cawemo.com/share/870694cf-b704-42c2-b0d7-a2637406d356

A new JIRA ticket for this issue in the context of form variables has beenc reated here: https://jira.camunda.com/browse/CAM-11357

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll try to change the model according your suggestion and I'll post the results. Cheers!

Comment: added latest JIRA link. Kindly accept the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that doesn't involve big changes in the model. Simply, I set the process start event as `Asynchronous Before`. Now, the timer start event can get the due date value and launch the remainder task as expected.

Cheers,